# SharePoint Online mobile view not displaying web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, mobile

I have a SharePoint Online environment. Inside it I have a web part page with a excel web access web part in it. It displays the content in the web part in pc view without any issue. But when I try to view it using SharePoint app in my android device it simply does not display the web part content. Is there anything I can do about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It’s the default behavior that excel web access web part cannot display in Mobile View.
As a workaround, I suggest you using PC view in mobile device.